# Registration and Login Using Realm

Tags: android, authentication, registration, realm

I am trying to do login and registration of user using Realm database. However am getting a bug as follows:

**Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.realm.Realm.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference**

Can someone help me please?

Below is my code for my registration and login..

**Code for Registration:**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Register";
EditText mEditTextFirstName, mEditTextLastName, mEditTextEmail,mEditTextPassword,mEditTextConfirmPassword;
Button mButtonSignUp;
Realm realm;
private MyRealmObject myRealmObject;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    try {
        realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mEditTextFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtfirstname);
    mEditTextLastName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtlastname);
    mEditTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtemail);
    mEditTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpassword);
    mEditTextConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtconfirm);
    mButtonSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignup);


    mButtonSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mEditTextFirstName.length() == 0) {
                showSnackBar("Enter FirstName");
                mEditTextFirstName.requestFocus();
            } else if (mEditTextLastName.length() == 0) {
                showSnackBar("Enter LastName");
                mEditTextEmail.requestFocus();
            } else if (mEditTextEmail.length() ==0) {
                showSnackBar("Enter a valid email");
                mEditTextEmail.requestFocus();
            }else if (mEditTextPassword.length() ==0) {
                showSnackBar("Enter a valid password");
                mEditTextPassword.requestFocus();
            }else if (mEditTextConfirmPassword.length() ==0) {
                        showSnackBar("Enter a valid Password");
                        mEditTextPassword.requestFocus();
            } else {

                try{

                    realm.beginTransaction();

                    myRealmObject = realm.createObject(MyRealmObject.class);
                    myRealmObject.setFirstName(mEditTextFirstName.getText().toString());
                    myRealmObject.setLastName(mEditTextLastName.getText().toString());
                    myRealmObject.setEmail(mEditTextEmail.getText().toString());
                    myRealmObject.setPassword(mEditTextPassword.getText().toString());
                    myRealmObject.setConfirmPassword(mEditTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString());


                    realm.commitTransaction();

                    showSnackBar("Save Success");


                } catch (RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showSnackBar("User found on db.");
                }

            }
        }
    });


}

private void showSnackBar(String msg) {
    try {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.relativeregister), msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



}
```

**Here is my code for Login..**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Home";
private EditText mEditTextEmail, mEditTextPassword;
private TextView txtlogin;
TextView Create;
private Realm realm;
private MyRealmObject myRealmObject;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    try {
        realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mEditTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtemail);
    mEditTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpswrd);
    txtlogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtlogin);
    Create = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtcreate);


    Create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    txtlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mEditTextEmail.length() == 0) {
                showSnackBar("Enter EMAIL");
                mEditTextEmail.requestFocus();
            } else if (mEditTextPassword.length() == 0) {
                showSnackBar("Enter password");
                mEditTextPassword.requestFocus();
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);


            }
        }

         private boolean checkUser(String email,String password) {
                RealmResults<MyRealmObject> realmObjects = realm.where(MyRealmObject.class).findAll();
               for (MyRealmObject myRealmObject : realmObjects) {
                   if (email.equals(myRealmObject.getEmail()) && password.equals(myRealmObject.getPassword())) {
                        Log.e(TAG, myRealmObject.getEmail());
                        return true;
                    }
    }


                Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(realm.where(MyRealmObject.class).contains("Email", email)));
               return false;
          }



        private void showSnackBar(String msg) {
            try {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.relativelogin), msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    });
}
```

**My RealmObject Class:**

```
public class MyRealmObject extends RealmObject {
private String FirstName, LastName,ConfirmPassword;
@PrimaryKey
private String Email;
private String Password;

public MyRealmObject() {
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}

public void setLastName(String LastName) {
    this.LastName = LastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.Email = Email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.Password = password;
}

public String getConfirmPassword() {
    return getConfirmPassword();
}

public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
    this.ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword;
}
```

}

Someone guide me where am wrong.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi Ishita,

I don't see a clear reason on why your realm instance would be null based upon your code.

Questions:
1) have you debugged the code right after realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext()) to see if it is null there? 
2) What version of Realm are you using? Realm.getInstance on 0.88.2 has been deprecated, if you're not on 0.88.2 try to upgdate and try to either use it with a RealmConfiguration or set the default configuration in your application. See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/ and section "The Default RealmConfiguration".

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: hello @Nerevar am having an issue with null, when I debug the code right after realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext(); 
I get 

savedInstanceState =null
realm=null

Comment: Hey again,

Okay, knowing that you now know the line where the problem occurs. I would strongly recommend you to change the way you create your realm instance.

Just to test if it works you can try to do this:

RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()).build();

Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);

Note that this code should only be for testing, If this works you can make the implementation better and more clear, look on the link I send in previous comment.

Did you look up the version you're using and if it's deprecated for you?

Comment: ya am using realm version 0.84.1'

when i try to update it to the latest version (0.88.2) I get errror in my gradle.
So am still using 0.84.1 @Nerevar

Comment: From that version they changed how Realm is initialised in the gradle file.
Look here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/ -> Installation.

Did it work for you to initialise Realm through the realm Configuration instead?

Answer (score 0):

Note that using `Realm.getInstance(context)` is deprecated. You should instead set a default RealmConfiguration in your application class and use `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` as described here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances

From a quick glance your code shouldn't be throwing exceptions though, but wrapping `realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext())` in a try/catch is dangerous, because if the method does throw, you will get the NullPointer you are seeing. I would remove that.

Comment: Hello  @Christian Melchior.. The issue with Null object reference is good now. 
Am having an issue while I check my username and password in my database while I login.. Can you check if this code is good I way i wrote it?
if (email.equals(myRealmObject.getEmail()) && password.equals(myRealmObject.getPassword()))

Comment: If `myRealmObject != null` then yes, it should be fine.